# Purchasing books that are out-of-print

Tags: books

I've just returned *[Principles of Modern Thermodynamics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750300191)* to the library. However, it is a terrific book that allowed me to understand thermodynamics that I have never would had I not run across this book. I have tried to purchase it, but it seems that this book is out of print. Therefore, my question is: **are there any vendors that might offer officially out-of-print books for sale?**

Comment: Sadly, nowadays many libraries are actively reducing their print holdings --- so, just wait, and monitor used book market. It is likely you will see a used copy one day.

Comment: Have you considered the "sequel" written by the same author? I assume since you've read the original book, you can tell how closely this one matches that one. Not the same book, but might be just as helpful. http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470843160.html#

Comment: Whether or not there exists a sequel is irrelevant. I haven't utilised the entire book, only chapters pertinent to the learning of concepts. But given my experiences with the book, and seeing the book as a gem, I'd very much love to add it to my collection shelf. Surely, finding an out-of-print book shouldn't be a bleak affair, or is it?

Comment: Abebooks (a shared platform for secondhand booksellers) is usually as good a bet as any for OOP material.

Comment: _finding an out-of-print book shouldn't be a bleak affair_ Well, in my personal experience, it can be extremely difficult. I have been searching a math book for over 5 years. I eventually get to see most of it on Google Books. But, it's not the same as a real paper book. I checked both ebay and Abebooks for you. Indeed, I couldn't find anyone who is selling this book.

Comment: You are allowed to make copies of out-of-print books for personal use, and you can have them bound.  Not as good as an original, but what else can you do for hard-to-find books.

Comment: @Kimball, your statement is not true in the US at all. Being in print currently has no effect on the copyright status. You might be able to make a Fair Use argument that since the book is out of print, your copying it did not impact the market for the book. But that's an argument that you would need to make in court when defending yourself against a lawsuit. The odds of such a lawsuit are low, but there is no provision that makes your suggestion specifically legal.

Comment: @BillBarth Hmm... some sites say it falls under fair use (e.g. http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/academic-and-educational-permissions/library-photocopying/ http://ask.library.ship.edu/faq/17387 ) but some find it debatable.  I suppose one could request permission from the publisher first if one wants to be safe.

Comment: @Kimball, I agree there's a Fair Use argument to be made, but that's a defense in a lawsuit not a blanket permission to do what you want. Defending copyright infringement lawsuits is expensive.

Comment: In a class I took a *long* while back the professor arranged to photocopy and bind a OOP book for us, and we paid copying and a fee for the publisher for the copy. I have no idea how he arranged it, though. Probably the people at the library which has a paper copy will be able to help.

Answer (score 17):

There is a number of websites that specialize on out-of-print or rare books. Those sites include [BookFinder](http://www.bookfinder.com), used books [section on AddALL](http://used.addall.com), rare or out-of-print [section on The Bookloft](http://www.thebookloft.com/out-print-hard-find-books) and others. In your particular case, the book that you're looking for (the 1995 edition of B. N. Roy's *Principles of Modern Thermodynamics*) can be easily found for sale on *Amazon UK* site [via BookFinder](http://www.bookfinder.com/search/?ac=sl&st=sl&ref=bf_s2_a1_t1_1&qi=KAJccOWrLXRvcrRbdgZpAF4QxjQ_1435913465_1:41:512&bq=author%3Db.%2520n%2520roy%26title%3Dprinciples%2520of%2520modern%2520thermodynamics) and [via AddALL](http://used.addall.com/SuperRare/submitRare.cgi?author=roy&title=Principles+of+Modern+Thermodynamics&keyword=&isbn=&order=PRICE&ordering=ASC&binding=Any+Binding&min=&max=&exclude=&match=Y&dispCurr=USD&timeout=20&store=ABAA&store=Alibris&store=Abebooks&store=AbebooksAU&store=AbebooksDE&store=AbebooksFR&store=AbebooksUK&store=Amazon&store=AmazonCA&store=AmazonUK&store=AmazonDE&store=AmazonFR&store=Antiqbook&store=Biblio&store=BiblioUK&store=Bibliophile&store=Bibliopoly&store=Booksandcollectibles&store=ILAB&store=Half&store=LivreRareBook&store=Powells&store=Wbm&store=ZVAB). Here's the resulting URL: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0750300191.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I know how to better find an out-of-print book.

Comment: There's also [Alibris](http://www.alibris.co.uk/), I've bought from them many used books (actually the books arrive from partnering bookstores).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Yes, I'm aware of it, I just didn't want to list more, hence "and others". +1

Comment: You can also ask in a regular book store. Often they have access to special antiquarian databases.